# Force Django to recognize a model field value as a template tag value?

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I am allowing users to create custom templates, and when doing so they are building off of my own base template with context variables.

So my own template that is used as a base will have a line such as..

`<h3>1.0: Contract Specifics for {{ first_name }}</h3>`

Now when the user edits this form I am escaping the curly brackets so they store as actual curly brackets in the form field when the user saves their custom template.

Now a user will click save and in the model field there will be raw HTML stored as a `TextField` and is stored in the database as such...

[image]

Now I need to render this in my django template later on but, I need `{{ first_name }}` to be replaced the actual context variable. unfortunately in my django template when I render this specific form field to display the HTML

```
      {% autoescape off %}
          {{ contract_detail }}
      {% endautoescape %}
```

it displays as..
`1.0: Contract specifics for {{first_name}}`

Is there anyway to force django to recognize this as a template variable and render this correctly, maybe I need some sort of custom functionality, or templatetag?

Comment: Can you take a look on the source of the rendered HTML page and check if the  curly brackets are still rendered as curly brackets instead of their HTML entities (`&#125;`)? If it's the HTML entities in there, can you try to replace `{% autosecape off }%` with `{{ contract_detail|safe }}` if that makes any difference?

Comment: When I inspect the page source it shows `{{ first_name }}` . Using the `{{ contract_detail|safe }}` displays just the same :/

Comment: Aah of course! Because it renders it just as a string inside the template. In order to have the placeholders replaced with variables, you have to render the content of `contract_detail` as a template itself, in your view and then use the rendered value in your template. [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) might come handy for that.

Comment: no, not `render_to_string`. I think you have to render [Template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Template) manually from the content of `contract_detail`

Comment: Will take a peek at that link and see what I can figure out!